# key map to call function in a plugin

Tags: vim

I have a visual map:

```
vmap 1 :call ExecuteSelection()<CR>
```

The `ExecuteSelection` function is defined in the plugin [vim-shell-executor](https://github.com/JarrodCTaylor/vim-shell-executor).

However, when I try to press the `1` key in visual mode, I receive the error:

```
E117: Unknown function: ExecuteSelection
```

**Question:** how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the plugin's source, that's the name of the *command*; the underlying function is named differently:

```
command! -range ExecuteSelection call ExecuteWithShellProgram("selection")
```

So, I'd recommend to use the (public) command in your mapping.

```
vnoremap 1 :ExecuteSelection<CR>
```

([You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.)

PS: Are you sure you want to map to `1`? That prevents you from supplying a *count*; e.g. you won't be able to shift the selection by 10 any more (`10>`)!

Comment: And `xnoremap` instead of `vnoremap`.

Comment: @romainl: Right, because `1` is a printable character that is supposed to replace a select-mode selection, not work on it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about not mapping to `1`, I'll look for an alternative :)